# UITextView text does not get cleared

Tags: uitextview

I have a small UIView that I hide/show in to show a message to the user.  The message itself is in a UITextView that I add to the small UIView that gets shown.

The sliding-in and sliding-out works fine - but the prior messages are not cleared. I have spent enough time to fix the problem - but to no avail.  Can someone lend me their eyes!!

[image]

Here is how the UITextField is created programatically:

```
@interface MessageVC : UIViewController {
    UITextView    *messageTV;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextView    *messageTV;

- (id)init;
- (void)showMsg:(NSString *)title;
@end
```

and

```
- (id)init {
  if (self = [super init]) {      
      self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 380, 320, 100)] autorelease];
      [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
  }
  return self;
}


- (void)showMsg:(NSString *)title {
    [self setMessageTV : [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 315, 90 )]];
    [[self messageTV] setBackgroundColor : [UIColor greenColor]];
    [[self messageTV] setTextColor : [UIColor whiteColor]];
    [[self messageTV] setText:@""];                            <<<<<<<< - does not clear the text
    [[self messageTV] setText : title];

    [self.view addSubview : [self messageTV]];
    [self.view setHidden:NO];
}

- (void) hideMessage {
    [self.view setHidden:YES]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll go out on a limb and ask why you're using a UITextView. I honestly have never needed to use a UITextView. Try changing it to a UILabel and see if the problem is specific to the UITextView. If you absolutely need a UITextView, let me know in a comment, but I have a suspicion that a UILabel is what you're after.

It appears that you are adding it as a subview every time. So you're actually creating multiple UITextViews and adding them on top of each other. You would either need to removeFromSuperview or just set the text of the instance variable.

Take these two lines out of showMsg and put them in viewDidLoad:

```
[self setMessageTV : [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 315, 90 )]];
[self.view addSubview : [self messageTV]];
```

Comment: Hi Vinnie.....  1. I started off using the UILabel, but some of the messages to be displayed were longer than what would fit in label - so now I'm using UITextView.  2.  You led me to correct path - adding multiple subviews.  Now the problem is fixed!!! :)  Thanks.